# PHP Check Sentence Contains Anything Other Than Letters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a script for splitting sentences. The code works but I want to skip sentences contains anything other than letters. Such as;

00:00:05,613 --> 00:00:16,505 
//I want to skip this

2

//and this

2.

//and this

The OMB guidance described in § 1.100(a) is published in subtitle A. Publication of the OMB guidance in the CFR does not change its nature—it is guidance and not regulation.

// I do not want to skip this

Comment: which is the one you dont want to skip?

Comment: The OMB guidance described in § 1.100(a) is published in subtitle A. Publication of the OMB guidance in the CFR does not change its nature—it is guidance and not regulation. 
this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(^[^a-zA-Z]*$)
```

This should work.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cA4wE0/6

Comment: I got another problem, it does not work when sentence is starting with number or special character?

Comment: Perfect! I have been working on this for hours. Thanks